# jQuery Animation Queue & This Function

Tags: jquery, html, animation

So I've got multiple articles of:

```
<article id="product-box">
    <header id="product-head"><!--thumbnail--></header>
    <footer id="product-foot"><span class="product-element">Product Title</span></footer>
</article>
```

and I want to add an effect where the product title(product-foot), which would be under the thumbnail to move 50 pixels to the right on the product box hover. Therefore the jquery code would be something like this, right?

```
$("#products > #product-box").mouseover(function(){
$("#products > #product-box > #product-foot").stop().animate({'margin-left': '20px'},500);});
$("#products > #product-box").mouseout(function(){
$("#products > #product-box > #product-foot").stop().animate({'margin-left': '0px'},500);});
```

However, since I have multiple articles the effect would work on every one of them, but I want it to work only on the one I'm hovering on. 
That is if I hover on the #product-box element, I want the #product-foot child element in that to animate. I was wondering if there would be a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple elements with the same ID? If so, **don't do that.** Element IDs must be unique.

Comment: Does everyone do that? I thought this would be a simplified way. Thus, so I have to create a new ID for every element? e.g `product-box1`, `product-box2`... etc?

Comment: No, you could use class. Like: '<article class="product-box">'.
And call it with $(".product-box")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#products > #product-box").mouseover(function(){

**the above code works only for single i mean first article.**

to make your code work for all articles you can do this

```
$("[id=product-box]").mouseover(   //..this makes code work on all product box elements
```

refer this [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

So to animate the children on the present product box you do this way

```
$("[id=product-box]").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).children("#product-foot").stop().animate({'margin-left': '20px'},500);});
```

Hope This Helps!!..

Comment: I was looking for something exactly like this, Thanks a bunch!